# JSON.parse reviver to sanitise data (stopping XSS)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, xss

I'm trying to reduce vulenrabilities in an old code base, specifically XSS attacks. The general pattern is:

- The site is a collection of HTML pages with  tags
- It uses jQuery
- Each page runs its own scripts
- Each page's scripts make an `$.ajax` request to a PHP file which returns `text/plain` JSON (via `json_encode($data)`)
- This data is then used to create dynamic HTML markup to inject into the DOM via either `$(selector).html`, `$(selector).append`, or occasionnally `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML =`

Here's a simplified example of the data flow:
**page.html**

```
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable"></table>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
$.ajax({url: "phpFile.php"}, function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $("#myTable tbody").html(data.redcuce(row=>"<tr><td>"+row.text"+</td></tr>", ""))
}
```

**phpFile.php**

```
//database query resulting in $data = [text->'<img src="x" onerror="alert(1)">', text->'Innocent value']
echo json_encode($data);
```

Some of the data retrieved is user input, so if a field contains `<img src="x" onerror="alert(1)">`, this executes when rendered in the table.

### Solution?

**I've passed the below sanitising function to `JSON.parse` to sanitise the data**

```
const sanitiseJson = (key, value) => typeof value === "string" ? DOMPurify.sanitize(value, { USE_PROFILES: { html: true } }) : value;
```

This uses the [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) library, which would be very easy for me to implement with search and replace.

As I understand it, this will remove potentially malicious HTML from the JSON object. This will prevent XSS attacks in this scenario.

1. Is this sufficient for sanitising fetched data that is then inserted into the DOM?
2. What are the other XSS vulenrabilities that are *not* addressed by this?

**Edit: note** I'm well aware that `.html()` etc is not the proper way to insert data, but this is an old, large code base (45k+ lines) and it's heavily entrenched, so my question is more about if this is an 'acceptable' solution in a pinch or if it doesn't come close

From my limited testing it seems to work, and as I (poorly) understand the way the data is processed I can't see how this would be circumvented easily

Comment: If you want to stop them, do not render `.html()`. Instead, alter the `.text()`. If you want to render HTML, use bbcode etc... `htmlentities()`/`htmlspecialchars()` and then convert `{{}}` or `[]` blocks into HTML so its a whitelisted approach.

Never put unstripped user input into `.html()`, simples.

Comment: Added a comment for clarity; rewriting all the code isn't really feasible - is there anything wrong with this approach given the scenario?

Comment: Why? I understand `.html()` shouldn't be used, but given how entrenched it is in the code I'm working with I'd like to understand what the pros/cons of this approach are

Comment: Added another comment for clarity, if you do not need to use `.html()` do not use it. If you do, then do not take a "blacklist" approach of trying to regex on the front-end. There is plenty of methods, like encoding (including such `&nsbp`), SVG's, and the list goes on to defeat a sanitizer.

Comment: @Jaquarh ok, so what approach would be appropraite? Are you suggesting some kind of sanitisation on the server before the json is echoed?

Comment: You still haven't been clear, do you need to render HTML from user input? If you don't then the simple solution is to not use the `.html()` method along side user input. If you do, then everything should be controlled server side, even prior to hitting your storage mechanism. "Is this sufficient enough" should be a question you repeat, review and monitor. Technology constantly changes and thus does the capabilities, tools, TTP's and opportunities for "legacy".

Comment: @Jaquarh so user input is stored in the database (via prepared statements with `bindParam`), a lot of the javascript pages fetch this data as JSON and then construct DOM elements as strings, like in the example given (the `data` array is reduced to a single string of HTML in plain text, which is then inserted). Are you suggesting the data should be sanitised before it is echoed?